# Learning Olympiad Level Combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, contest-math, big-list, book-recommendation

Combinatorics has always been my weakest point, I want to improve it.

There are such problems like:

"Five friends should give each other gifts. They have made a gift each, as they should
give away to one of the others. In how many ways can they distribute gifts such
that everyone gets a gift, and no one gets the gift they have made?"

From a specfic country's olympiad.

Can somebody tell me, which text, or what resource to use to be able to learn these types of questions?

Comment: You can have a look at the books mentioned in combinatorics section in the [list of olympiad books](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Wiki/index.php/Olympiad_books) at AoPS. They mention [100 Combinatorial Problems](http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/Forum/viewtopic.php?t=412125) (Parvadi),
[102 Combinatorial Problems: From the Training of the USA IMO Team](http://books.google.com/books?id=kdMilHngC4UC) (Andreescu, Feng) and
[Problems in Combinatorics and Graph Theory](http://books.google.com/books?id=TO_uAAAAMAAJ) (Tomescu).

Comment: (And a few other books about combinatorics, but not concentrated specifically on problem solving, are also mentioned there.)

Answer (score 1):

I used Bogart's *Enumerative Combinatorics Through Guided Discovery* in one of my courses which helped me learn much about elementary combinatorics, predictably from the title in a more "do this problem and learn the rules yourself" kind of way. You might also look at Mikolos Bona's *A Walk Through Combinatorics* which is more traditional textbook style.